# Accessing Object Memory Address

Tags: python, object, memory-address, repr

When you call the `object.__repr__()` method in Python you get something like this back:

> ```
> <__main__.Test object at 0x2aba1c0cf890>
> ```

Is there any way to get a hold of the memory address if you overload `__repr__()`, other then calling `super(Class, obj).__repr__()` and regexing it out?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

The [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) has this to say about `id()`:

> Return the "identity'' of an object.
>   This is an integer (or long integer)
>   which is guaranteed to be unique and
>   constant for this object during its
>   lifetime. Two objects with
>   non-overlapping lifetimes may have the
>   same id() value. (Implementation note:
>   this is the address of the object.)

So in CPython, this will be the address of the object. No such guarantee for any other Python interpreter, though.

Note that if you're writing a C extension, you have full access to the internals of the Python interpreter, including access to the addresses of objects directly.

Comment: This is **not** a universal answer to the question; it only applies to CPython.

Comment: Note to self:  The guarantee does not apply to multiprocessing

Comment: Some ways to use it (to compare the value it contains): https://forum.freecodecamp.com/t/python-id-object/19207

Comment: What does an object's `lifetime` (and what does it mean for lifetime to `overlap/not overlap`) refer to in this context?

Comment: @MinhTran because the id is the memory address of the object, it is guaranteed unique within the process, and while the object exists. Some time after the object is garbage collected the memory may be reused. A non overlapping lifetime would mean the original object no longer exists when the new object is created. So this limitation means you can't safely use id() to create a hash of an object to store off, free it, and later reinstate it.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix well, *it is not a universal that the number you are seeing in an object `repr` is the memory address*.

Answer (score 87):

You could reimplement the default repr this way:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<%s.%s object at %s>' % (
        self.__class__.__module__,
        self.__class__.__name__,
        hex(id(self))
    )
```

Comment: I know this is old, but you can just do `return object.__repr__(self)` or even just do `object.__repr__(obj)` whenever you need this instead of making a new class

Comment: @Artyer: What does this comment have to do with the original question? The answer posted here is recreating the address as requested by the original question. Wouldn't you have to string mangle if you did it the way you suggest?

Comment: This seems like the best answer to me. Just try making an object(), print it, then print hex(id(object)) and the results match

Comment: @Rafe Your answer is a long winded way of doing `__repr__ = object.__repr__`, and isn't nearly as fool proof, as there are a variety of situations where this doesn't work, e.g. an overrided `__getattribute__` or a non-CPython implementation where the id isn't the memory location. It also doesn't z-fill, so you would have to work out if the system is 64bit and add the zeroes as necessary.

Comment: @Artyer: My example shows how to construct a repr. We often add custom information (and I would say this is good coding practice as it aids in debugging). We use this style heavily and I have never run in to your edge cases. Thanks for sharing them!

Answer (score 64):

Just use

```
id(object)
```

Comment: which gives a number. ... What's next? Can i access the object with that number?

Comment: You can check this [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) @JLT

Answer (score 35):

There are a few issues here that aren't covered by any of the other answers.

First, [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) only returns:

> the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.

---

In CPython, this happens to be the pointer to the [`PyObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html) that represents the object in the interpreter, which is the same thing that `object.__repr__` displays. But this is just an implementation detail of CPython, not something that's true of Python in general. Jython doesn't deal in pointers, it deals in Java references (which the JVM of course probably represents as pointers, but you can't see those—and wouldn't want to, because the GC is allowed to move them around). PyPy lets different types have different kinds of `id`, but the most general is just an index into a table of objects you've called `id` on, which is obviously not going to be a pointer. I'm not sure about IronPython, but I'd suspect it's more like Jython than like CPython in this regard. So, in most Python implementations, there's no way to get whatever showed up in that `repr`, and no use if you did.

---

But what if you only care about CPython? That's a pretty common case, after all.

Well, first, you may notice that `id` is an integer;* if you want that `0x2aba1c0cf890` string instead of the number `46978822895760`, you're going to have to format it yourself. Under the covers, I believe `object.__repr__` is ultimately using `printf`'s `%p` format, which you don't have from Python… but you can always do this:

```
format(id(spam), '#010x' if sys.maxsize.bit_length() <= 32 else '#18x')
```

<sub>* In 3.x, it's an `int`. In 2.x, it's an `int` if that's big enough to hold a pointer—which is may not be because of signed number issues on some platforms—and a `long` otherwise.</sub>

Is there anything you can do with these pointers besides print them out? Sure (again, assuming you only care about CPython).

All of the [C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html) functions take a pointer to a `PyObject` or a related type. For those related types, you can just call `PyFoo_Check` to make sure it really is a `Foo` object, then cast with `(PyFoo *)p`. So, if you're writing a C extension, the `id` is exactly what you need.

What if you're writing pure Python code? You can call the exact same functions with [`pythonapi`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls) from `ctypes`.

---

Finally, a few of the other answers have brought up [`ctypes.addressof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.addressof). That isn't relevant here. This only works for `ctypes` objects like `c_int32` (and maybe a few memory-buffer-like objects, like those provided by `numpy`). And, even there, it isn't giving you the address of the `c_int32` value, it's giving you the address of the C-level `int32` that the `c_int32` wraps up.

That being said, more often than not, if you really think you need the address of something, you didn't want a native Python object in the first place, you wanted a `ctypes` object.

Comment: well this is the only way to store mutable objects in maps/sets when identity is important...

Comment: @Enerccio The other uses of `id`—including using them to hold mutable values in a `seen` set or a `cache` dict—don’t depend on any way on the `id` being a pointer, or related in any way to the `repr`. Which is exactly why such code works in all Python implementations, instead of only working in CPython.

Comment: yeah, I used `id` for it, but I mean still even in java you can get address of object, seems strange there is no way in (C)Python since that one has actually stable gc that won't move objects thus address stays the same

Comment: @Enerccio But you don't want to use the address of an object for a cacheable value—you want to use the `id` fo an object, whether it's an address or not. For example, in PyPy, `id` is still just as useful as a key in CPython, even though it's usually just an index into some hidden table in the implementation, but a pointer would be useless, because (like Java) the object can be moved in memory.

Comment: @Enerccio Anyway, there _is_ a way to get a pointer in CPython. As explained in the answer, CPython explicitly documents, as an implementation-specific detail, that the `id` of an object is the pointer to the object's location in memory. So, if you have any use for the pointer value (which you almost never do, as also explained in the answer) in CPython-specific code, there is a way to get it that's documented and guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 14):

Just in response to Torsten, I wasn't able to call `addressof()` on a regular python object. Furthermore, `id(a) != addressof(a)`. This is in CPython, don't know about anything else.

```
>>> from ctypes import c_int, addressof
>>> a = 69
>>> addressof(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invalid type
>>> b = c_int(69)
>>> addressof(b)
4300673472
>>> id(b)
4300673392
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get something suitable for that purpose with:

```
id(self)
```

Answer (score 4):

With [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-ctypes.html), you can achieve the same thing with

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> ctypes.addressof(a)
3077760748L
```

Documentation:

> `addressof(C instance) -> integer`
>   Return the address of the C instance internal buffer

Note that in CPython, currently `id(a) == ctypes.addressof(a)`, but `ctypes.addressof` should return the real address for each Python implementation, if

- ctypes is supported
- memory pointers are a valid notion.

**Edit**: added information about interpreter-independence of ctypes

Comment: >>> import ctypes
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> ctypes.addressof(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invalid type
>>> id(a)
4493268872
>>>

Comment: I concur with Barry: the above code results in `TypeError: invalid type` when I try it with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but if you're still programming, in python 3 these days... I have actually found that if it is a string, then there is a really easy way to do this:

```
>>> spam.upper
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x1042e4830>
>>> spam.upper()
'YO I NEED HELP!'
>>> id(spam)
4365109296
```

string conversion does not affect location in memory either:

```
>>> spam = {437 : 'passphrase'}
>>> object.__repr__(spam)
'<dict object at 0x1043313f0>'
>>> str(spam)
"{437: 'passphrase'}"
>>> object.__repr__(spam)
'<dict object at 0x1043313f0>'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to recovery the value from the 'id' command, here it the TL;DR.

ctypes.cast(memory_address,ctypes.py_object).value

[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-value-from-address-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the memory address/location of any object by using the '**partition**' method of the **built-in** '**`str`**' type.

Here is an example of using it to get the memory address of an object:

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 27 2020, 02:08:17)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> object.__repr__(1)
'<int object at 0x7ca70923f0>'
>>> hex(int(object.__repr__(1).partition('object at ')[2].strip('>'), 16))
0x7ca70923f0
>>>
```

*Here*, I am using the built-in '`object`' class' '`__repr__`' method with an object/item such as `1` as an argument to return the string and then I am partitioning that string which will return a tuple of the string before the string that I provided, the string that I provided and then the string after the string that I provided, and as the memory location is positioned after '`object at`', I can get the memory address as it has partitioned it from that part.

And then as the memory address was returned as the third item in the returned tuple, I can access it with index `2` from the tuple. But then, it has a right angled bracket as a suffix in the string that I obtained, so I use the '`strip`' function to remove it, which will return it without the angled bracket. I then transformed the resulted string into an integer with base 16 and then turn it into a hex number.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that `id(object)` gets the object's address in the default CPython implementation, this is generally useless... you can't *do* anything with the address from pure Python code.

The only time you would actually be able to use the address is from a C extension library... in which case it is trivial to get the object's address since Python objects are always passed around as C pointers.

Comment: Unless you use the built-in `ctypes` toolkit in the Standard Library. In which case you can do all sorts of things with the address :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `__repr__` is overloaded, you may consider `__str__` to see the memory address of the variable.

Here is the details of [`__repr__` versus `__str__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr) by [Moshe Zadka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122683/moshez) in StackOverflow.