# const void* pointer in ctypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, buffer, constants, ctypes

If I have a writable `buffer`, I can use `ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer` function to obtain a C pointer to this buffer.

How to deal with non-writable buffers, however? How to form a `const` pointer that I can pass to C code that expects a `const void*` without resorting to making a writable copy of the non-writable buffer?

I considered `c_void_p.from_address` but buffers (and memoryviews) don't seem to expose their address.

---

Some clarification:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> b = buffer("some data that supports the buffer interface, like a str")
>>> ptr = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: buffer is read-only
>>> ptr = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer_copy(b)    # works, but has to copy data
>>> ptr = ctypes.CONST(c_void_p).from_buffer(b)  # (I'm making this one up)
>>> ptr = ctypes.c_void_p.from_address(???)      # could work; how to get addr?
```

That would work with `void some_api(const void* read_only_data)` like:

```
>>> ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(some_lib).some_api(ptr)
```

The method with `from_buffer_copy` works, but needs to copy the buffer first. I'm looking to way to work around the requirement of the buffer being writable, because nobody is going to write there and I want to avoid redundant copying of data.

Comment: Can you give some example code?

Comment: There we go, I hope it's clear now

Comment: So this may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121396/accessing-object-memory-address . I have tried playing around with the suggestions therein, but with limited success. The trick is most likely to write a PythonC_API function to take the buffer and return its address. That should be relatively easy to do.

Comment: In the case of a `void*`, a `str`/`unicode` (Python 2.x) or `bytes`/`str` (Python 3.x) can just be passed directly to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a Python string to `char*` with ctypes, and that points to actual memory there Python string data is stored.

Feel free to double-cast.