# Why are these tuples returned from a function identical?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Let's say I have a function:

```
def get_tuple():
    return (1,)
```

In IDLE if I call:

```
get_tuple() is get_tuple()
```

It will print `True`

If I call:

```
(1,) is (1,)
```

It will print `False`

Do you know why? 
I cannot find an explanation in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The CPython implementation of Python stores constant values (such as numbers, strings, tuples or frozensets) used in a function as an optimization. You can observe them via `func.__code__.co_consts`:

```
>>> def get_tuple():
...     return (1,)
...
>>> get_tuple.__code__.co_consts
(None, 1, (1,))
```

As you can see, for this function the constants `None` (which is the default return value), `1` and `(1,)` get stored. Since the function returns one of them, you get the exact same object with every call.

Because this is a CPython implementation detail, it's not guaranteed by the Python language. That's probably why you couldn't find it in the documentation :)

Answer (score 6):

Python optimizes the return value.
Because it is easy for the interpreter to see that the returned tuple will be the same each time, and it is an immutable object, it returns the same object (the exact same one. same memory address).
Here, when you do `a is b` you actually ask `id(a) == id(b)`.

Comment: Do you know how to find it in Python documentation?

Comment: It's important to note that particular *implementations* of Python may perform such an optimization. The language itself makes no such guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of addresses in the memory. Just try to print them via 
[print memory address of Python variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408472/print-memory-address-of-python-variable)

Comment: @Kristofee yes for each call it returns same, but I cannot understand why, because i expect each function call will return new object.