# Where are the actual values of variables stored?

Tags: python, variables, memory

It's known that variables don't store values but the addresses to those values instead.
That's why when we say `x=y` and change any of them, the change will affect the other, because they point to the same address in memory.

If the variable names store addresses to where the values are, then where are the actual values stored?

I mean, is there a separate place for storing the addresses and another place for storing the actual values where those addresses point to?

Everything is in the RAM, but how the RAM is organized? and how is there a difference between a place in memory that stores an address and another place that stores a real value?

Comment: At the address in memory pointed to by the variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print memory address of Python variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408472/print-memory-address-of-python-variable)

Comment: *"If the variable names store addresses to where the values are, then where are the actual values stored?"* - At those addresses.

Comment: What exactly do you think an address *is*? (Hint: in ordinary English usage, what does that word mean? If I said I had a letter with "an address" written on it, would you be able to tell me where the recipient lives?)

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear if you're asking how Python, how CPython, how the Operational System, etc. are handling the memory.

Answer (score -1):

There is a builtin function called `id()` which will print actual memory addres. But there is an interesting thing for storing actual values.

```
a = 256
b = 256
a is b  # True
a == b  # True
a = 257
b = 257
a is b  # False
a == b  # True
```

So as you can see `is` operator checks if a has same address link as b, and `==` actualy compares using `__eq__`. But Python caches integers from -5 to 256 and when you assign them twice, in reality Python just assigns same memory address cached.

Comment: [Then again...](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P1HBVsHI1JwrCUoXFGXmlWgkKmQWKyRp/v8PAA)

Comment: @KellyBundy is it? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YlAWk9fe-dT83-Hwa5m3hGKOgeJWLVXv?usp=sharing

Comment: What I mean is that it depends on context, how you're running the code. And your answer doesn't say how it does.

Comment: @thanos.a well this identifier is [indeed memory address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408472/print-memory-address-of-python-variable)