# python - error while using matplotlib.pyplot.scatter function for the first time

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just wanted to get started on using the matplotlib library for the first time.

So I type the following commands:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = sp.genfromtxt("web_traffic.tsv", delimiter = "\t");
x = data[:, 0];
y = data[:, 1];
x = x[~sp.isnan(y)];
y = y[~sp.isnan(y)];
plt.scatter(x, y);
```

And I have received the following error :

```
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection object at 0x246abd0>
```

I have no idea what is causing this, I have just installed the required packages, `scipy`, `matplotlib` and it returned to me that particular error. I tried to google it but with no results.

I am using openSuse as OS and python came by default. My main purpose is to start learning using the `scykit learn` package.

Can you give me any advice on how to get over this error?

Comment: that is basically output of `__repr__`, see [this](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/121508/625914)

Comment: I would recommend `np.isfinite` in place of `~np.isnan`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not an error message. It's a string representation of an object.

If you ran the code above in an interactive shell, then what you see is a string representation of the value returned by the `plt.scatter` function.

To actually open the window, you usually need to call `plt.show()` at the end.

Or if you want it to be interactive, it is [suggested](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iep_/3_VzHrGpvPE) to set `interactive: True` in your `.matplotlibrc`.

On an unrelated note, semicolons are not needed at the end of the line in Python.

Comment: But shouldn't I receive the plot window? Or how do I open that?

Comment: I am using the `iep` ide. How should I proceed to see the plot window?

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the matplotlib example for plt.scatter():

```
"""
Simple demo of a scatter plot.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2 # 0 to 15 point radiuses

plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

As the previous answer stated, you will have to call plt.show() to actually render the plot.