# What does this mean <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000002244592F1A8>?

Tags: python

I have a url:

```
https://enterpriseefiling.fcc.gov/dataentry/api/download/dbfile/Current_LMS_Dump.zip
```

Let

```
u1 = ['https://enterpriseefiling.fcc.gov/dataentry/api/download/dbfile/Current_LMS_Dump.zip']
```

I run the following code in my python interpreter

```
import requests, io
r = requests.get(u1, stream=True)
io.BytesIO(r.content)
```

I get the following response

```
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x000002244592F1A8>
```

My question is: what does this mean? Where is 0x000002244592F1A8? What does 0x000002244592F1A8 refer to?

Comment: It's the internal ID of the BytesIO object, which is automatically returned by the interpreter when you reference an object on the command line. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am just trying to understand what these functions return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When python needs to print out an object, and the object doesn't otherwise have a built-in method that tells the interpreter *how* to print it out (for example, `requests.Response` and python's built-in `list` and `dict` types *do* have this sort of instruction), python uses this format:

```
<[objecttype] object at [pointer]>
```

where `pointer` is literally a pointer to the object's location in memory. That's what you see here: when you do `io.BytesIO(r.content)` in your interpreter, you create an `io.BytesIO` object.

A different method tends to get called when, on the interpreter, you do

```
>>> print(<object>)
```

rather than just

```
>>> <object>
```

and the `io.BytesIO` class certainly has methods you can use for more useful output, if you look at its documentation. Try assigning it to a variable instead of printing it:

```
b = io.BytesIO(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks! So the pointer here is a pointer formatted as a hexidecimal and it identifies the actual physical memory register in the computer's hardware?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `0x000002244592F1A8` here is the formatted [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) of the object in memory. I say "formatted", because, if you do `id()` on the same object, the representation will be a little different (it will be formatted as an `int` or a `long` instead of a pointer address:

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: obj = io.BytesIO()

In [3]: obj
Out[3]: <_io.BytesIO at 0x10da1ca70>

In [4]: id(obj)
Out[4]: 4523674224
```

To convert the `id()` to the format you see, you can do something like this (stolen from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285749/3642398)):

```
In [5]: format(id(obj), '#010x' if sys.maxsize.bit_length() <= 32 else '#18x')
Out[5]: '       0x10da1ca70'
```

This ^^ is not particularly useful, but it just shows you how `id()` lines up with what you are seeing.

The reason you are seeing it is just that it is displayed as part of the default `__repr__()` for the `BytesIO` object.

Comment: @RafaelC please see the rest of the original post, plus the SO link I posted. I am currently editing the post to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

> What does 0x000002244592F1A8 refer to?

It refers to the *identity* of the object. The number is an implementation detail (in CPython it happens to be the address of the object in memory, the same number returned by the `id` builtin), but what you can count on is that the number will be different for every `BytesIO` object currently extant in the process.

That kind of information is included in the `__repr__` of many objects because it can come useful when debugging, allowing one to distinguish different objects that might have identical content.