# <iterator object at 0x00A1DB50> What is the meaning of 0x00 etc.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

So if I do something like:

```
>>> s ='abc'
>>> it = iter(s)
>>> print(it)
<str_iterator object at 0x10543eac8>
```

or:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> it = iter(s)
>>> it
<iterator object at 0x00A1DB50>
```

We have in both cases the indication that *"it"* is an iterator (with the specification of what kind of iterator in the first example). What I am curious about is the meaning of the string that follows. 0x10543eac8 or 0x00A1DB50.

**Does anyone know its meaning and/or use?**

Thank you,
Den

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121396/accessing-object-memory-address

Answer (score 1):

In CPython, it's the memory address where that object is stored, which corresponds to the value returned by `id`. It can be useful for debugging purposes to see whether two prints refer to the same object or not (given that, at some moment of time, at a given address can exist only a single Python object).