# Address Python prints for an identifier

Tags: python

```
>>> def func(): pass
>>> func
<function func at 0x10ce60400>
```

What is that address for? (The `0x10ce60400`)
Where and what does it point to?

(I am talking about CPython 3.7)

Comment: It's some memory location, *possibly*, depending on your flavour of Python. It has no real useful meaning.

Comment: That's just Python's way of saying "I don't know how to show you anything meaningful about this object", in this case a function object.  It's simply an object identifier.  It may or may not refer to a physical memory address.  The identifier is not useful to you other than possibly to distinguish between two objects.

Comment: Covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121396/accessing-object-memory-address, As @deceze said, it might be a memory location (CPython) or might just be a number. It is an 'identity' which is guaranteed to be unique during the lifetime of the object.

Comment: I'm not trying to get more information on a function, just interested in what this address is