# Where does the heap exist which stores objects in python?

Tags: python

As I was studying about the memory management in python.
I came across the heap.
So a question was raised in my mind. Where is the heap stored?

Some websites where I have looked for an answer do not have a satisfactory explanation.

Comment: It's in the memory of the Python process, possibly using a function like `malloc()` in C.

Comment: You can access an object's entry by `id()`, i.e. `a=[1,2,3]; addr=id(a)`, see [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121396/accessing-object-memory-address).

Answer (score 0):

stack and heap are generic concepts regarding how the operating system manages the memory allocated to processes during run time. These concepts are not exclusive to Python programming language.
Please, checkout [this very informative stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap/1213360) for a general idea if these concepts are new for you.
Once familiar with stack and heap checkout this [Python document](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html) which gives more information about memory management in python.

[Another link](http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs1410/textbook/4.Pointers/memory.html) explaining stack and heap concept.

hope this helps !