# how to get memory location of a variable in Python

Tags: python

When we look at the following code,

```
my_var = "Hello World"
id(my_var)
```

The statement `id(my_var)` returns the address/location of the string-object "Hello World"

I was wondering if we have any command, with which I can get the address/location of `my_var`

---

I am trying to understand memory in Python. For example, in C-programming I can get the address of variable and pointer in following way

```
int var;
int *var_ptr = &var;

printf ("%d", var_ptr);  % Prints address of var
printf ("%d", &var_ptr); % Prints address of var_ptr
```

Comment: You're thinking far too low level for a language like Python. `id(my_var)` returning the address of the String isn't even standard. That is, afaik, an implementation detail of CPython.

Comment: hmm.. may be.. I just started understanding how "Garbage collection" works in Python. So, I got this doubt...
+ I truly started appreciating C :)

Comment: Does this answer to your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121396/accessing-object-memory-address

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Object Memory Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121396/accessing-object-memory-address)

Comment: You really don't ever need to worry, or even think about addresses while dealing with Python unless you're doing something niche like interfacing with C.

Comment: C includes memory access as part of its data model. Python does not. As far as the *language* is concerned, every single variable lookup could be backed by an HTTP GET call to some remote server. (Slow, yes, but it wouldn't change the semantics of the language in any way.)

Comment: Even as an implementation detail, nothing prevents Python from moving an object to a different location in memory during garbage collection, as long as its ID remains unique.

Comment: @yossefaz : No, the response provided in that answer, actually returns the address of the "Hello World" (I just ran code, and re-checked)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for your response.. May be it is not possible in Python to go that "deep"

Comment: @chepner: Hmm.. Okay.. That may be possible.

Comment: @AravindD.Chakravarti I'm curious, why are you wanting to "go that deep"? Is there a particular reason, or just interest?

Comment: A Python variable doesn't even *have* an address of its own.  Whatever value it holds at any given moment in time will have an address, but that will usually change when a new value is assigned to the variable.

Comment: @Carcigenicate : Just interest :-) I understand this is not required during development of any code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can’t**, but the reason is so fundamental that I think it worth posting anyway.  In C, a pointer can be formed to any **variable**, including another pointer.  (Another pointer *variable*, that is: you can write `&p`, but not `&(p+1)`.)  In Python, *every* variable is a pointer but every pointer is to an **object**.

A variable, not being an object, cannot be the **referent** of a pointer.  Variables can however be **parts** of objects, accessed either as `o.foo` or `o[bar]` (where bar might be an index or a dictionary key).  In fact, every variable is such an object component except a local variable; as a corollary, it is impossible to assign to a local variable from any other function.  By contrast, C does that regularly by passing `&local` to whatever other function.  (There is an exception to the "any other function": `nonlocal` variables can be assigned, but every local variable used in a nested function is implemented by implicitly creating a `cell` object as the underlying value of the variable and interpreting usage of the variable as referring to an **attribute** of it!)

This distinction is readily illustrated by C++ containers: they typically provide `operator[]` to return a **reference** (a pointer that, like a Python reference, is automatically dereferenced) to an element to which `=` can be applied, whereas the Python equivalent is to provide both `__getitem__` (to return a reference) and `__setitem__` (which implements **`[]=`** *all at once* to store to a variable).

In CPython’s implementation, of course, each Python variable is a `PyObject*` variable, and a `PyObject**` to one can be used for internal purposes, but those are always temporary and do not even conceptually exist at the Python level.  As such, there is no **equivalent** for `id` for them.