# How to extract a memory address from inside a Python object

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm using a binary Python library that returns a Buffer object. This object is basically a wrapper of a C object containing a pointer to the actual memory buffer. What I need is to get the memory address contained in that pointer from Python, the problem is that the Buffer object doesn't have a Python method to obtain it, so I need to do some hacky trick to get it.

For the moment I found an ugly and unsafe way to get the pointer value:

I know the internal structure of the C object:

```C
typedef struct _Buffer {
  PyObject_VAR_HEAD PyObject *parent;

  int type; /* GL_BYTE, GL_SHORT, GL_INT, GL_FLOAT */
  int ndimensions;
  int *dimensions;

  union {
    char *asbyte;
    short *asshort;
    int *asint;
    float *asfloat;
    double *asdouble;

    void *asvoid;
  } buf;
} Buffer;
```

So I wrote this Python code:

```python
# + PyObject_VAR_HEAD size
# + 8 bytes PyObject_VAR_HEAD PyObject *parent
# + 4 bytes from int type
# + 4 bytes from int ndimensions
# + 8 bytes from int *dimensions
# = 24
offset = sys.getsizeof(0) + 24

buffer_pointer_addr = id(buffer) + offset
buffer_pointer_data = ctypes.string_at(buffer_pointer_addr, 8)
buffer_pointer_value = struct.unpack('Q', buffer_pointer_data)[0]
```

This is working consistently for me. As you can see I'm getting the memory address of the Python Buffer object with `id(buffer)`, but as you may know that's not the actual pointer to the buffer, but just a Python number that in CPython happens to be the memory address to the Python object.

So then I'm adding the offset that I calculated by adding the sizes of all the variables in the C struct. I'm hardcoding the byte sizes (which is obviously completely unsafe) except for the PyObject_VAR_HEAD, that I get with `sys.getsizeof(0)`.

By adding the offset I get the memory address that contains the pointer to the actual buffer, then I use ctypes to extract it with `ctypes.string_at` hardcoding the size of the pointer as 8 bytes (I'm on a 64bit OS), then I use `struct.unpack` to convert it to an actual Python `int`.

**So now my question is:** how could I implement a safer solution without hardcoding all the sizes? (if it exists). Maybe something with ctypes? It's OK if it only works on CPython.

Comment: If you only need to support CPython, then using `id()` is ok. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121396/accessing-object-memory-address

Comment: Thanks, yes I guessed that. What about getting the sizes of all those C variable types instead of hardcoding them?

Comment: Saw `short *asshort;` and had to laugh  and ask "What kind of _hort_ "? ;-)

Comment: @ciclopez you can't really do much about the offset. Even knowing the sizes there can be padding between structure fields. You can use `sizeof` from `ctypes` for the sizes of certain data types.

Comment: I really want to know why you need the pointer from Python code.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli isn't there some way of accessing the actual C Object variables from Python by using ctypes?

Comment: @ciclopez how? Once a C program is compiled, you lose that information. You don't have information on the types that compose a struct just by "looking" at it. You might manage to do something with debugging information embedded in the binary file (if any, which I doubt), but that's a long and painful process.

Comment: @nategoose Basically I want to compress a sequence of images really fast and they are generated by a software that spits them as the mentioned Buffer object, so I need to pass this buffer to another library that I made in Cython, but don't want to copy the buffer as it's very inefficient, specially if it has to be converted to another Python object (they are big images at a high frame rate), so I'm passing the pointer and working with that.

Comment: @ciclopez: Why not just make the Cython library know how to process the struct _Buffer wrapper object?  That seems like the cleanest way to do this.

Comment: @nategoose It's a bit more complicated than what I explained, I tried to simplify it. I can't do that because the library I'm doing is intended to work as a plug-in for different softwares, and each software generates the image buffers in different ways. In some softwares I have direct access to the buffer pointer, but in the one I'm dealing with now I have this problem. This Buffer object has a method to return the values as a Python list, but that is extremely inefficient, so I'm trying to get the pointer.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I finally found a safer solution with your hint about `ctypes.sizeof()` and investigating about C Struct padding, I posted an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a safer solution after investigating about C Struct padding and based on the following assumptions:

- The code will only be used on CPython.
- The buffer pointer is at the end of the C Struct.
- The buffer pointer size can be safely extracted from void * C-type as it's going to be the biggest of the `union{}` made in the C struct. Anyway there will be no different sizes between data pointer types on most modern OS's.
- The C Struct members are going to be exactly the ones shown in the question

Based on all these assumptions and the rules found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38144117/8861787,
we can safely say that there will be no padding at the end of the struct and we can extract the pointer without hardcoding anything:

```python
# Get the size of the Buffer Python object
buffer_obj_size = sys.getsizeof(buffer)

# Get the size of void * C-type
buffer_pointer_size = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_void_p)

# Calculate the address to the pointer assuming that it's at the end of the C Struct
buffer_pointer_addr = id(buffer) + buffer_obj_size - buffer_pointer_size

# Get the actual pointer value as a Python Int
buffer_pointer_value = (ctypes.c_void_p).from_address(buffer_pointer_addr).value
```