# How get a pointer value in QAxObject with python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qaxobject

I need use `QAxObject` to read some PLCdata.I Can connect PLC successful but the problem is that I can't read data from it.The reason in below.

```py
class Test(QAxWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setControl("ActUtlType.ActUtlType.1")
        self.dynamicCall("SetActLogicalStationNumber(int)", 1)

        ret = self.dynamicCall("Open()")
        value = 12
        ret = self.dynamicCall("ReadDeviceRandom2(QString, int, int&)", "D300", 1, value)
        print(ret, value)
```

[image]
<sub>info: ReadDeviceRandom2 method, szDeviceList is PLC address, ISize is read data size, IpsData is
to store read data</sub>

The problem is that method `ReadDeviceRandom2` need to pass a  int address to it, but python has no int address.So the sample code not working.
In this situation how can i pass a pointer to it and read it.

The output:
[image]

---

Then I use other method

```py
import win32com.client

plc = win32com.client.Dispatch("ActUtlType.ActUtlType.1")
plc.ActLogicalStationNumber = 1
plc.open()

value = 0
ret = plc.ReadDeviceRandom2("D300", 1, value)

print(ret, value)
```

The output, it work fine.
[image]

Comment: what is the output of `print(self.dynamicCall("ReadDeviceRandom2(QString, int, int&)", "D300", 1, 0))`?

Comment: It always output `0 12`,I try to use win32com.client.Dispatch("ActUtlType.ActUtlType.1") to read, it read fine.But qt method not working.

Comment: You may take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121396/accessing-object-memory-address

Comment: @Kfcaio The method you specified not working in pyqt system.

Comment: Can't you pass the object itself to method? I don't think it's possible to get memory address and deference it at Python level

Comment: @Kfcaio The "id" is not the pointer of the python object but is an identifier that python sets to each object.